# AngularJS / GoogleMaps (Hide markers at all times)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using AngularJS and the GoogleMaps API, my team and I noticed that it is quite hard to get markers to do exactly what you want them to.

We are using polygons (instead of markers) on our map page to represent certain areas.  When those areas are clicked, an infoWindow pops up with relevant information.  When the user clicks another polygon, the infoWindow goes to that polygon with no problem and no marker shows up on the original parking lot.  This is all good and well, but when the user closes an infoWindow given from any polygon, the red marker shows up again.

Bottom Line:  Is there a way to permanently hide markers so that even when an infoWindow is closed (close clicked), it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove):

To remove a marker from the map, call the setMap() method passing null as the argument.

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

You can also play around with the [full sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove). It includes hiding and deleting markers functionality.